# For G++ on MacOS how to add default include dir /usr/local/include and default library search path /usr/local/lib?

Tags: c++, g++, include-path, library-path

I have installed libfmt with homebrew. Files could be found in `/usr/local/lib/libfmt.dylib` and and `/usr/local/include/fmt`. Formally they are links to `/usr/local/Cellar/...`.

G++ does not search /usr/local/include/ and /usr/local/lib/ by default. And I would not like to add them on project level.

```
❯❯❯ g++-9 -print-search-dirs
install: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/
programs: =/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin18/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin18/bin/
libraries: =/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin18/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin18/lib/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/../../../x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.3.0/../../../
```

Comment: With the `-I` and `-L` flags.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I know. But I wrote "I would not like to add them on project level"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the relevant environment variables in your shell, e.g:

```
export CPATH=...
export LIBRARY_PATH=...
```

Full documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html)